# Unable to install pyhook and pywin32

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.3, pywin32, pyhook

I'm tring to install pyhook and pywin32, but it can not find python 3.3 which I is installed (and so is 2.7) in the registry. Thats all it really tells me, I'm using Windows 7 with AMD64 bit CPU.

Answer (score 1):

You use installer for 32bit architecture. Please check this installer for 64bit: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook.